# Mediation -- How can the ZY mediated path be larger than the XZ path?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

Consider the classic mediation path diagram, with $O$ influencing $Z$ (the mediator) and $Z$ affecting $Y$.

**My question is: Does it make sense that the path $ZY$ (coefficient 5) be larger than the path $XZ$ (coefficient 3)?**

What kind of mechanism could produce something like this?

Given that $Z$ is caused by $X$, how can a path/effect further along this causal chain be larger than an earlier path/effect?

What is even more peculiar is that if you run a regression ($Y = X + Z$) and set $X = 0$, the total effect and the direct effect will disappear but the effect of $Z \rightarrow Y$ will still be 5. How is that possible (from a logical standpoint)?

Imagine a concrete example, X = social origin, Z = education and Y = income. Imagine that education is completely explained by origin ($X \rightarrow Z$), how then can education have a larger effect on income, than origin has on education?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you are asking why causal effects in the future could ever be larger than causal effects in the past, and this is a nonsensical question. The answer is "they just can be". There is no reason why one effect should be smaller than another when the two effects are independent of each other.

Comment: (First not helpful to brand my question as "nonsensical"). Second, give me an example of something (Z) that is caused by something else (X) but end up having a larger effect on an outcome (Y). What kind of social processes can produce something like that? Again take the canonical example of the Origin-Education-Destination example in social mobility.

Comment: I think the answer lies in the sizes of the random error of $Z$. If other factors are associated with $Z$ but not associated with $X$, which in this model will end up in the random errors of $Z$, then it can make sense that $Z$ can have a larger effect on $Y$ than its mediated path. However, I think these factors would need to  graphed.

Comment: The effect of a local high school's social media campaign on getting people vaccinated, and the effect of the vaccine on death. The campaign likely does very little, if anything, but the vaccine has a large effect. Take any cause with a large effect and think of all the tiny things that barely affect it. They all satisfy this criterion. The effect of X on Z has nothing to do with the effect of Z on Y; you just happened to pick an example where the former is smaller than the latter, but all the tiny, barely consequential causes of education fit your criterion.

Comment: Take your example. Imagine that without a campaign people don't take up the vaccine. Vaccine are the mechanism, or mediator, of the campaign. Campaign improves health through the vaccine.
If there is no campaign, no one take up the vaccine, so no effect. Therefore, it is not possible to set campaign to 0 and still have an effect of the vaccine.

Comment: That's not true, because people will still take the vaccine without the campaign. A campaign is just one of many reasons people might take a vaccine. And a campaign could be small or weak (or even ineffective) without affecting the effectiveness of the vaccine. The cause of people getting a vaccine has nothing to do with the causal effect of the vaccine.